# Hide Dojo Dialog in WCM

Tags: dojo, wcm, textboxio

I have a .jsp file in which I define my popUp with dijit/Dialog:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/Dialog" data-dojo-id="ampPopUp" title="Amp">
```

But when I show my page, I don't need it to being show, I need to show it through a external button (a button in a TextBoxIO frame). The point is that I can't reach out the way to hide it until I press the Amp-Button.

The logic is in a .js which is imported in the .jsp

Thank you all.

Comment: there are couple of ways of doing it. If possible, post the complete code